# Magento 2 wysiwyg editor hide/show button not showing with custom category attribute?

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, custom-attributes, category-attribute, magento2.3.3

I have create custom category attribute as wysiwyg editor under content fieldset.

Attribute is showing and working fine but I want to add Hide/Show Editor button with atribute.

How can I do this?

I am using below code in `adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml`

```
   <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="category_information">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_information</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Information</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">category-desc</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Let me know if my solution helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line in your `ui_component` file

```
<item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

with this

```
<item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

After changing this value from `false` to `true` please run below commands.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, it is working.

Comment: Thanks @kishan its usefull for me